# Can't stop my startup script on debian squeeze

Tags: bash, node.js, deployment, debian

I'm trying to set up a deployment for a webapp I'm doing and I'm having some problems with start script. Here's what I done so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=/webroot/webapp.com
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules
NODE=/usr/local/bin/node

test -x $NODE || exit 0

function start_app {
  NODE_ENV=production nohup "$NODE" "$DIR/production/WebApp/server.js"
  echo $! > "$DIR/production/WebApp/webapp.pid"
}

function stop_app {
  kill `cat $DIR/production/WebApp/webapp.pid`
}

case $1 in
   start)
      start_app ;;
    stop)
      stop_app ;;
    restart)
      stop_app
      start_app
      ;;
    *)
      echo "usage: webapp.com {start|stop}" ;;
esac
exit 0
```

I can start it like that but when I try to stop it I get this:

```
ssh mydomain.com /etc/init.d/webapp.com restart
cat: /webroot/webapp.com/production/WebApp/webapp.pid: No such file or directory
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your `webapp.pid` file isn't actually being created until after your node app exits, and it won't exit until your startup script kills it, which it can't do without the `.pid` file.

You need to run node in the background so the code that creates the `.pid` file actually gets a chance to run:

```
NODE_ENV=production nohup "$NODE" "$DIR/production/WebApp/server.js" &
```

Comment: Note also that Debian includes `start-stop-daemon` which is used in lots of startup scripts; you might want to check out the manpage.

Answer (score 1):

The error is fairly straight forward:

```
cat: /webroot/webapp.com/production/WebApp/webapp.pid: No such file or directory
```

Does this file exist?

If not, the question is why. My hunch is that this command is failing:

```
echo $! > "$DIR/production/WebApp/webapp.pid"
```

But since you never verify that it actually created the file, you don't catch the error.

Does the directory `/webroot/webapp.com/production/WebApp/` exist? Does your user have read/write/execute permission on that directory?

Another possibility, since this directory is being placed in `/webroot/webapp.com/production/WebApp` is that it's getting deleted by the application. You may have to store the pid file elsewhere. Have you tried that?